# Should defects be considered when giving schedule estimates?

Tags: test-management, test-estimation

I was asked to provide estimates on how long the tasks would take in QA standpoint. Should the defects that might be encountered be considered? Or should I assume that the tasks would be defect-free? I would be really thankful if I could get some pointers or readings that would help me understand the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you (almost) always need to count with some additional time spent on defects. Whether or not you specifically say so (as in creating a special task for it), it's a different question.

> I was asked to provide estimates on how long the tasks would take in QA standpoint. Should the defects that might be encountered be considered?

I can see at least two approaches:

1. you give one estimate where you take into account possible defects
2. you give an estimate without time for defects, but each of these defects will later get their own estimate (they might be attended to in the next iteration)

Whether you choose 1. or 2. depends on how you work in the company.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I would take previous test cycles and number of defects with this team, product or developer in a account. If it is new team/product make a guesstimate based on your previous experience.

I never had a test run where I didnt find a defect, or struggled with the configuration, infrastructure, and or setup to be able to start testing.

This estimate cannot be precise, my delivery estimates (including testing and fixing defects) are between -50% and +500% ;-) Estimating software development from idea to production is hard.

Answer (score 0):

> Should the defects that might be encountered be considered?

If your development process support this then yes - estimate the time to reproduce and write them down.

> Or should I assume that the tasks would be defect-free?

As we (development team) are only human and there is always a chance to have defects in the code and thus should be taken into consideration when estimating.

Comment: I know that there's no such thing as defect-free software, however, what I'm asking is if it needs to be considered in providing estimates. Also, that extra comment of yours would not answer the question so better leave that out.

Comment: You know it will happen and it will take additional time and yet you ask if you need to count it?

Comment: Just like what @puzzle mentioned above, I can do it, but there should be a different estimate for working on that defect.